# gstreamer rtpjpegdepay received invalid RTP payload

Tags: gstreamer-1.0

I want to stream RTP video between a Sender and a Receiver. It works fine if I stream the video via UDP using these commands :

**SENDER**

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-video-index0 ! jpegenc ! rtpstreampay ! udpsink host=172.17.30.78 port=5200
```

**RECEIVER**

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

But when I try to save the video to a file

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/v4l/by-id/usb-AVEO_Technology_Corp._USB2.0_Camera-video-index0 ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay  ! filesink location=test
```

And then send it via UDP using these commands

**SENDER**

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test ! udpsink host=172.17.30.78 port=5200
```

**RECEIVER**

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

The receiver fails to decode the stream and it show this error

```
AVERTISSEMENT : de l’élément /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGDepay:rtpjpegdepay0 : Impossible de décoder le flux.
Information de débogage supplémentaire :
gstrtpbasedepayload.c(492): gst_rtp_base_depayload_handle_buffer (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpJPEGDepay:rtpjpegdepay0:
Received invalid RTP payload, dropping
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one difference when saving to a file. A file is a continous stream of data while UDP sends packets, each with a size information. This size information helps identifying the boundary of a logically decodable element. This information is lost when saved to a file.